# Transform widget with CSS :after background-image in a reusable component

Tags: html, css, less

I have a widget on my front page that I want to use many times but with another background image. I was trying to put another element that could reproduce the behavior from CSS :after but without success. Do you know the best approach for this?

HTML

```
<div class="widget-2 panel no-border bg-primary widget widget-loader-circle-lg no-margin">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="pull-bottom bottom-left bottom-right padding-25">
            <br>
            <h3 class="text-white">My Title</h3>
            <p class="text-white hint-text hidden-md">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (less)

```
.widget-2 {
  &:after {
    background-image: url("@{assets-url}/img/social/person-cropped.jpg");
  }
}
```

Result
[Widget with backgroud-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM68R.png)

Comment: Are you asking how you can have different background images for the same widget markup/style?

Comment: I belive that I need to remove the :after and then put it in a JS or a another HTML tag with the background information. ex: <div style="backgroud-image: ...."></div>. What do you think?

Comment: cannot figure out, what is your final goal. if you need a random background each time, you may achieve it in few ways but not with CSS.

Comment: Exactly @markoffden, do you have any hints for me?

Comment: well, you cannot achieve it with CSS. what I would do is create an array in JS with background url strings, then on page load you get the random string and put it as you element background

Comment: @markoffden You can do this with CSS only ... I just did

Comment: LGSon, guess I didn't fully understand the desired goal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way ... CSS only

HTML

```
<div class="widget-2...." style="background-image: url(...); ">
  ....
</div>
```

CSS

```
.widget-2 {
  background-size: 0;
}
.widget-2:after {
  background-image: inherit;
}
```

And of course one can have the resources as classes, if one feel that is more convenient than in markup

HTML

```
<div class="widget-2 img1 ....">
  ....
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img1 {
  background-image: url(...);
}
.widget-2 {
  background-size: 0;
}
.widget-2:after {
  background-image: inherit;
}
```